# Given is density with unknown interval limits - Determine the maximum likelihood estimations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

> Given $X_1,..X_n$ observations of a population with densitiy
>
> $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} \frac{1}{b-a} \text{ if } x \in (a,b)\\ 
> 0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ else }
> \end{matrix}\right.$$
>
> where interval limits $a$ and $b$ are unknown. Determine the maximum
>   likelihood estimations for $a$ and $b$.

This is example task from exam and I like to know how solve it correctly.

When I understand formula of maximum likelihood estimation correct,

This is maximize when $(b-a)$ is as small as possible but also important that $(a,b)$ include all the data. For this reason we have

$$a = \min(x_1,..,x_n)$$

and

$$b=\max(x_1,..,x_n)$$

I hope this is all correct like that or all wrong? : /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. Recall the definition of the MLE, that is 
$$
\hat{\theta} = \arg\max_{(a,b) \in \Theta} \frac{1}{(b - a)^n}\, ,
$$
and $a \le X_i \le b$ for all $i$, thus you have to choose the closest statistics to $b$ and $a$ over $\Theta$ in order to maximize the likelihood (over the parametric space). Namely, 
$$
\hat{a} = \min\{X_1,...,X_n\}\, ,\quad \hat{b} = \max\{X_1,...,X_n\} \, .
$$
But note that you need the equality in $a \le X_i \le b$, otherwise the MLE is not in the parametric space.